# How to manage externally created addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core

In my application the private keys are created and stored on a HSM. When a new private key is created on the HSM, it returns the corresponding public key. With this public key I create a bitcoin address. Since these externally generated addresses are not part of a wallet, I'm unable to get the UTXOs of this address. Now my big questions is: How can I get the UTXOs of this address without importing it into a wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin Core has a `scantxoutset` command. You give it [output script descriptors](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md) (which specify `scriptPubKey`s) and it will scan the UTXO set and return the UTXOs that have `scriptPubKey`s that match the given descriptors.

Comment: Is there also an rpc endpoint for scantxoutset?

Comment: Yes. I found it: curl --data-binary '{"id":"1","jsonrpc":"1.0","method":"scantxoutset","params":["start", [{"desc":"addr(msJaKN7KCGARZrKWyy169GzztFLx7aTRBf)"}] ] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332